# How can I pass a function to a class's method in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a thing you can pass your service check code to and alert if it returns false - in python how can I pass code to an instance of a thing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def service_check():
    print('service is up')

class Alerter():
    def watch(f):
        f()

watcher = Alerter()
watcher.watch(service_check())
```

returns:

```
service is up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./service_alert", line 12, in <module>
    watcher.watch(service_check())
TypeError: watch() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Add `self`: `def watch(self, f):`. Also, change `watcher.watch(service_check())` to `watcher.watch(service_check)` to pass the function, not the return value.

Comment: This might be a good use for a decorator or seen from a higher perspective: a testing framework like pytest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working Code

```
def service_check():
print('service is up')

class Alerter():
  def watch(self,f):
    f()

watcher = Alerter()
watcher.watch(service_check)
```

As @Tomothy32 mention there are 2 changes.

1. Need to add Self in  def watch(self,f). This is because, whenever an object calls its method, the object itself is passed as the first argument.
2. The second we should pass function pointer watcher.watch(service_check) instead of function calling  watcher.watch(service_check()).

Answer (score 1):

watch() function is missing an argument to self due to which the above program throws an exception. Also, You should just pass the name of the function to pass its address in watcher.watch(service_check) instead of making a call via service_check().
Program should work fine with these changes as suggested by @arunraja-a.